# Why are iFrames not being loaded in Safari on some pages?

Tags: html, ios, macos, iframe, safari

we have encountered an issue on one of our intranet pages where an iFrame is not loading the head or html code.

The issue only occurs in Safari (El Capitan, Yosemite and iPhones) and is only happening on one particular page. When inspecting the html we can see the iframe code, but when we expand the #document section there is the html tag is empty.

In the console there are no errors that show up. The only thing we notice is that there is significantly less data being loaded and about 15 less calls.

Could anybody give us any insight as to what might cause an iframe to not load properly? It seems like a timing thing as we can use javascript to insert the iframe tag into an empty div after the document is ready then it works.

Thanks!

edit:
Sample iFrame code:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="true" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/[YOUTUBEID]?rel=0&wmode=opaque" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Is the content in the iframe loaded from your domain? or a different one?

Comment: @JohnConde The iframe is actually just youtube embed code. It doesnt seem to matter which video we use, they all seem to fail. I placed a sample of the iframe code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I know the issue is old but did you tried adding a setTimeout to append the iframe code or adding an onload event ?

```
setTimeout(function() {
    div.innerHTML = '<iframe allowfullscreen="true" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/[YOUTUBEID]?rel=0&wmode=opaque" frameborder="0"></iframe>';

    div.querySelector("iframe").addEventListener("load", function() {
      console.warn("Video loaded");
      div.querySelector("iframe").focus();
    });
}, 100);
```

Comment: Did you tried the code before posting it? Double quotes are not proper and would result in error.

Comment: You are right, this is fixed!
I had a similar issue where Youtube and Vimeo embeds was not properly loading with Safari (Version 10.1) and adding this code fixed it.

Answer (score -2):

is the parent domain http://??? I have a similar issue at the moment where I have an https url housed inside the iFrame but the parent site is using a non secure http protocol. Try changing the src="https://www.youtube.com/embed to src="http://www.youtube.com/embed
Do you get the same issue?

Comment: This ends up breaking the iframe for all browsers unfortunately.